# Why timeit shows incorrect measurement with this numba function?

Tags: python, numba, timeit

This code snippet measures execution time of a Numba function using performance counter:

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np
from time import perf_counter
from timeit import timeit

x = np.arange(1_000_000).reshape(1000, 1000)

@nb.njit(fastmath=True) # Set "nopython" mode for best performance, equivalent to @njit
def go_fast(a): # Function is compiled to machine code when called the first time
    trace = 0.0
    for i in range(a.shape[0]):   # Numba likes loops
        trace += np.tanh(a[i, i]) # Numba likes NumPy functions
    return a + trace              # Numba likes NumPy broadcasting

print(go_fast(x))
t0 = perf_counter()
go_fast(x)
t1 = perf_counter()
print(f'{t1-t0:9.6f}s')
```

It outputs approximately `0.002597s`. When I try to measure performance with `timeit`, I can't get the result excluding the compilation time, even tough I specifically call `go_fast()` once in the startup code in order to get this function compiled. This line:

```
print(timeit('go_fast(x)', setup='print(go_fast(x))', globals=globals(), number=100))
```

returns times around `0.1023`, which is obviously wrong. I read a few SO posts on this subject, incorporated their findings, and the problem is still not solved.

Comment: Now try with `number=10`, `number=1000` etc.

Comment: You can wrap `go_fast(x)` in a `for _ in range(100)` loop (wih `perf_counter()` outside the loop, to compare.

Comment: @MichaelDorner The OP has already taken care of the compilation before measuring the timing; see the code.

Comment: See also https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#timeit.Timer.timeit . Note that the command line variant of timeit, `python -m timeit`, *averages* the output of the fastest 5 or so loops. So it does something extra. That may be what you are used to.

Comment: @9769953 Thank you. I thought `number=` was a number of measurements. If only I've read the manual: *Time number executions of the main statement.*

Comment: It *is* the number of measurements, in a way. It just doesn't average them.

Answer (score 0):

You can get an idea of the compilation overhead if you remove the `setup` keyword and use `timeit.repeat` instead of `timeit.timeit`. Using `setup` as described in the OP actually *does* exclude compilation.

As already alluded to in the discussion above, `timeit` returns the total time it takes, this can be divided by the number of runs to convert to the duration of a single call if needed.

It's probably not a good idea to use `number=1` in general, but for the sake of example:

```py
number = 1
result = timeit.repeat('go_fast(x)', globals=globals(), number=number, repeat=10)
```

On my machine results in:

```py
[0.2409477001056075,      # <-- including compilation
 0.0023898999206721783,
 0.0021232999861240387,
 0.0022255999501794577,
 0.002602699911221862,
 0.0022704999428242445,
 0.0026885000988841057,
 0.002612600103020668,
 0.00272749993018806,
 0.0022243999410420656]
```

Setting `number=100` obfuscates the impact of compilation a little. Note how the total duration is now about 100x longer compared to `number=1`:

```
[0.4830413998570293,      # <-- including compilation
 0.22851129993796349,
 0.22516979998908937,
 0.2598621998913586,
 0.26912679988890886,
 0.2639903000090271,
 0.22695020004175603,
 0.22762689995579422,
 0.23626239993609488,
 0.25013910001143813]
```

The Python documentation suggests that taking the `min()` of several repeats is probably the most meaningful result:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#timeit.Timer.repeat