# Python benchmark: timeit vs default_timer

Tags: python, benchmarking, timeit

I recently started learning python and I'm looking for a method to mesure how fast my code implementations are and compare them with others.

I stambled across the `timeit` library, and I found it very useful for my purpose but I struggle to understand the output I get from using the `timeit()` function vs using `Timer()`.

Take this code example:

```
from timeit import timeit


def maxWealth(accounts):
    m = 0
    for account in accounts:
        tot = sum(account)
        if tot > m:
            m = tot
    return m


list1 = [[1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 45, 6]]
print(timeit(lambda: maxWealth(list1)))
```

output: `0.41396119981072843`

Then this example:

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer


def maxWealth(accounts):
    m = 0
    for account in accounts:
        tot = sum(account)
        if tot > m:
            m = tot
    return m


list1 = [[1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 45, 6]]
start = timer()
result = maxWealth(list1)
stop = timer()
print(stop-start)
```

output: `6.400048732757568e-06` (which is 0.0000064s)

If i keep going with the executions, the timeit measures seem a little more consistent then using the default_timer, but they are really different values tough.

Which method is more accurate? From the docs I see both methods use a `Timer()` instance but If so, why am I getting this very different values?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72510531/why-timeit-shows-incorrect-measurement-with-this-numba-function

Comment: yes, that definetly answered my questions. Thanks